# Let $X$ be a locally compact ,Hausdorff space and $\{U_n\}$ be a sequence of dense open sets in $X$ .Show that $\cap_nU_n$ is dense in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How can I prove that if $X$ be a locally compact , Hausdorff space and $\{U_n\}$ be a sequence of dense open sets in $X$ then  $\cap_nU_n$ is dense in $X$.
Let, X be a Hausdorff space , X a locally compact dense subspace of Y then show that X is open in Y.

Comment: This is just Baire Category Theorem and you can get  a proof from Wikipedia.

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CQN

Comment: Shouldn't $Y$ be Hausdorff for the second question? BTW, not a good idea to ask two unrelated questions in one post..

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,U\ne\emptyset\,$ be open in $\,X.\ $ We want to prove that

$$ U\cap\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n\,\ne\emptyset $$

By local compactness, there is compact subspace $\,W\subseteq U\,$
which has non-empty interior $\,W_0\,$ in $\,X.\, $ Then the closure $\,V\,$
of $\,W_0\,$ is a non-empty compact contained in $\,W\subseteq U.\ $ It's elementary
that

$$ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\quad V_n\,:=\,V\cap U_n $$

is dense and open in $\,V.$

Since compact spaces
have the Baire property, we obtain

$$ \emptyset\,\ne\,\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n
          \,\subseteq\,U\cap\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n $$

This proves the theorem.  *Great!*